# Error: Local variable referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python

I have a python websocket client code

```
run_once1 = True
run_once2 = False

def on_message(ws, message):

    if 'Temp' in message:
        if run_once1 is True:
            #Run this code once
            print("Temp is present")
            run_once1 = False
            run_once2 = True

    else:
        if run_once2 is True:
            #Run this code once
            print("Temp is not present")     
            run_once1 = True
            run_once2 = False       

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("CLOSE ")

def on_open(ws):
    print("OPEN")
    msg = "<MESSAGE>"
    ws.send(msg)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(URL, on_message= on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```

So in the above code, I am opening a websocket and then whenever I receive a new message, `on_message()` function is called. Inside this function, I am looking for tag `Temp` in the message. If it is present, I just want to print that and run it once. Next when `Temp` is not present, I want to print it and also run that code just once. But the above code gives error:

`error from callback <function on_message at 0x000001D35366D840>: local variable 'run_once1' referenced before assignment`

`error from callback <function on_message at 0x000001D35366D840>: local variable 'run_once2' referenced before assignment`

Where should I write these variable so that it do not give me this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to assign to a global variable inside a function you need to declare it as global in that function. For example:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    global run_once1
    global run_once2

    # remainder of function as before
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is declared out of your function's scope, ie. your function doesn't see your variables that are declared out of it's indentation (nor variables that are declared inside the function change the values of same-named variables outside.

What you need to do is to pass those variables as function arguments, e.g.:

```
run_once1 = True 
run_once2 = False

def on_message(ws, message, run_once1, run_once2):

    if 'Temp' in message:
        if run_once1 is True:
            #Run this code once
            print("Temp is present")
            run_once1 = False
            run_once2 = True

    else:
        if run_once2 is True:
            #Run this code once
            print("Temp is not present")     
            run_once1 = True
            run_once2 = False       
    return run_once1, run_once2

run_once1, run_once2 = on_message (ws, message, run_once1=run_once1, run_once2=run_once2
```

However, in your case it won't work, because you want to have direct call to this function. Then, to preserve the state, I would write 'on_message' as class:

```
class OnMessage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.run_once1 = True
        self.run_once2 = False

    def __call__(self, ws, message):
        if 'Temp' in message:
            if self.run_once1 is True:
                #Run this code once
                print("Temp is present")
                self.run_once1 = False
                self.run_once2 = True

        else:
            if self.run_once2 is True:
                #Run this code once
                print("Temp is not present")     
                self.run_once1 = True
                self.run_once2 = False

on_message = OnMessage() 

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("CLOSE ")

def on_open(ws):
    print("OPEN")
    msg = "<MESSAGE>"
    ws.send(msg)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(URL, on_message= on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```